# How to get intersected face when raycasting against buffer geometry

Tags: three.js, raycasting, buffer-geometry

I'm raycasting against a scene.

The geometry of intersected object is "BufferGeometry". 
Part of Intersected object is

```
{
  distance: 494.77924415158327
  face: Face3 {a: 732, b: 733, c: 734, normal: Vector3, vertexNormals: [], …},
  faceIndex: 732,
  index: 732,
  object: Mesh {id: 16, uuid: "F1E299F1-927D-4CD8-ACF6-3A5AA528EACD", name: "collide_main", type: "Mesh", parent: Group, …},
  point: Vector3 {x: -3.025193341955971, y: 2.63172597487887, z: -4.237102099257478, isVector3: true, …},
  uv: Vector2 {x: 0.46554459963387684, y: 0.6888516128730314, isVector2: true, …}
 }
```

I need to get the face of that object. I'm doing this for that.

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry( INTERSECTED.object.geometry );
var faces = geometry.faces;
var intersectedFace = faces[INTERESECTED.faceIndex];
```

But many time INTERSECTED face contains an index which is not there in faces. for Example in the above case INTERSECTED.faceIndex is 732, but the faces i obtaines contains array of only 200 faces.

How can i get the intersected face.

Comment: Did I get it correctly, that first, you find a face index of a buffer geometry, and then you convert that geometry into a usual one, and try to apply that face index to the new usual geometry (which has nothing in common with the original buffered geometry)?

Comment: yes. Can how can i get new faceIndex for the usual geometry.

Comment: Is your buffer geometry non-indexed?

Comment: yes. Inside bufferGeometry index is null. I think this means it's non-indexed

Answer (score 1):

Use intersection face a, b, c properties to get x, y, z from position bufferattribute:

```
let positionAttribute = bufferGeometry.attributes["position"];
let aVertex = new THREE.Vector3(positionAttribute.getX(intersection.face.a), positionAttribute.getY(intersection.face.a), positionAttribute.getZ(intersection.face.a));
let bVertex = ...;
let cVertex = ...;
```

Comment: how should i use aVertex, bVertex and cVertex to get face from normal geometry

Comment: You can use those vertices to construct triangle and render it. Why do you want to deal with normal geometry if you have buffer geometry in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can access vertices of a face via its index like that (I see the reason for that is to change the color of a face; a non-indexed geometry is just a triangle soup):

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var planeGeom = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(10, 10, 10, 10);
var planeGeomNonIndexed = planeGeom.toNonIndexed();
console.log(planeGeomNonIndexed);
var colors = [];
planeGeomNonIndexed.attributes.position.array.forEach(p => {
  colors.push(1, 1, 1);
});
planeGeomNonIndexed.addAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(colors), 3));
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeomNonIndexed, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors
}));
scene.add(plane);
scene.add(new THREE.Mesh(planeGeom, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "black",
  wireframe: true
})));

var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
var intersects = [];
window.addEventListener("mousedown", onMouseDown, false);

function onMouseDown(event) {
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(plane);
  if (intersects.length === 0) return;

  let faceIndex = intersects[0].faceIndex;

  planeGeomNonIndexed.attributes.color.setXYZ(faceIndex, 1, 0, 0);
  planeGeomNonIndexed.attributes.color.setXYZ(faceIndex + 1, 1, 0, 0);
  planeGeomNonIndexed.attributes.color.setXYZ(faceIndex + 2, 1, 0, 0);
  planeGeomNonIndexed.attributes.color.needsUpdate = true;
}

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
```